# Should I clear the dist directory before every distribution - and how?

Tags: python, package, setuptools

In order to upload my package to PyPI, I'm using:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

Now I would like to upload an updated version.

Should I simply run the same commands? The old dist files are still in the `dist` directory.

Is the good practice to first clean `dist/` and then build and upload? If so, what is the cleanest way to do so?

EDIT: Things seem to work by simply doing `twine upload --skip-existing dist/*`. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the good practice to first clean dist/ and then build and upload?

Yes.

```
rm -rf build dist *.egg-info
```

PS. I usually do this cleanup immediately **after** release. See my release scripts for examples ([SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/8cf109f4bc7084e6a177a4c4893c3cc90c4c8d95/devscripts/release#L28), [CheetahTemplate](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/5fbc4b7b07baf1f205efc2bc9b67824ea74bf4b1/devscripts/release#L34), [my small projects](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Aphdru+%22rm+-rf+build+dist%22&type=Code))